# Remove Default Profile Fields from Drop Downs

Tags: drupal, profile, custom-fields

Ok, when creating new profiles within CiviCRM for events or contribution pages, some of my customers are using fields that do not coincide with the information that the payment processor recognizes, so the "My Billing Address is the Same" doesn't carry over all of the information.

Is there a way to remove some of the "default/standard" Individual/Contact profile fields available in CiviCRM with Drupal?

- CiviCRM Version: 4.6.4
- Drupal 7

[image]

Let me know if you need any further clarification.

I really appreciate any help on this one! :)

Thank You!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the "billing address" you collect for credit cards should only contain the fields actually needed by the credit card processor, as that's all it is used for. The home address can collect additional fields, and the user would need to enter that additional info as it won't be collected for the credit card.